# No repository found error while installing ABAP ADT

Tags: abap, abap-adt

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed

> session context was:(profile=C_Users_ssp2_eclipse.jee-2019-09_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
>
> No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.sap.ui.treemap,3.0.0

Tried many suggestions which are available in other Q/A but not worked for me:

- I removed all folders of Eclipse and installed again to install ABAP Developmemt Tool. In Help->Eclipse Marketplace clicked on Updates.
- Unchecked Read Only option for Eclipse folder. But this error always appears. when tried to install ADT

Trying to install ADT using below link for softwares
https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/2019-09

Comment: Hi Sachin, welcome to Stack Overflow. You mention you have tried many suggestions. Please could you provide some details to help people answer your question?

Comment: Hi James, I removed all folders of Eclipse and installed again to install ABAP Developmemt Tool. In Help->Eclipse Marketplace clicked on Updates. Unchecked  Read Only option for Eclipse folder. But this error always appears. when tried to install ADT using link https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/2019-09

Comment: The install can't find the `com.sap.ui.treemap` plug-in - this is not a standard Eclipse plug-in so messing around with your Eclipse installation isn't going to help. You will have to find out from the tool authors how to get this plug-in

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your time and suggestions. 
I able to install ADT and other softwares which are required successfully. I just removed all Eclipse folders and a folder named .P2 as well. Then tried to install all from beginning then it worked.
Thanks All.

Comment: so mark this as an answer, please